# Find out if a socket equals null

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How do I find out if a socket = null or undefined

Example of what I want to achieve

```
if(socket.username == NULL){
givenulldata()
}
```

Here is my socket deleting on disconnect, however some times the user hasn't actually left the website and I don't want to annoy them with a please refresh page thing, when it's unneeded. due to deleting on laptop running out of battery or there wifi disconnecting and reconnecting (more common issue for mobile devices) etc.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
if(!socket.username) return;
delete username[socket.username];
});
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to check this. The `io.on('connection', function(socket) {` function only works if the socket is defined.

Comment: I delete sockets when users logout. However, I have found when people end up disconnecting from the internet and things it deletes their socket. So i thought it would be an easy fix to find out if the socket has nothing in it and then just refresh the process of logging in. meaning as long as the user is present there always going to be logged in. So i just need to find out, how you detect if a socket is null or undefined or maybe just searching for an error would work. But i'm also unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

undefined and null are falsy values, so their conversion to boolean results into false

you can try:

```
if((!socket) || (socket && !(socket.username))){
    givenulldata()
}
```

By this you check if socket doesn't exist or if it exists but doesn't have a username

Answer (score 0):

There's an improved way of how to satisfy the topic starter's question:

```
if (!isSocket || !socket.username) {
    givenulldata()
}
```

How does it work?

If `!isSocket` is true, it will give null data. JS won't even go to `!socket.username` ! But if `!isSocket` is false, then it's assumed that `isSockt` is true, and JS goes to checking if there's a username or not. In this way the code looks cleaner